# When 'the' not pronounced as 'thee' in front of vowels

Tags: pronunciation

- the university
- the one

*The* pronounced as the way it is because *university* is pronounced as y-, and *one* w-. Is there any other case it should not be 'thee' even though in front of vowels?

Also I found this article on Wikipedia and would like to hear your opinion.

> In most dialects, "the" is pronounced as /ðə/ (with the voiced dental fricative /ð/ followed by a schwa) when followed by a consonant sound, and as /ðiː/ (homophonous with thee) when followed by a vowel sound or used as an emphatic form.[2] In modern American English, however, there is an increasing tendency to limit the usage of the latter pronunciation to emphatic purposes and use the former even before a vowel.

Comment: Extreme emphasis sometimes makes us use the pronunciation “thee” as in:  “Introducing... for one night only... THE one... THE only... Jane D!!”  Another example, “I’m not just promising a party, I am promising THE BEST party you have ever been to!”  But even in these sentences it is possible to us the ordinary ðə too without really losing any emphatic force.

Comment: But I have missed commenting on your main point. “The” is almost always pronounced ðə in my dialect and in most standard British and American dialects I hear. You are incorrect in your claim that it only comes before a noun with an initial vowel.  For example, listen to this video and wait until she says, “the most common way people speak...” about 1 minute in: https://youtu.be/Zi2Z0Twx6cI

Comment: An example in British English now. The speaker sounds quite formal in her pronunciation but the first “the” I detect (at about 0.50) in “...the most important video I’ve ever done...” is definitely ðə. A few seconds later she says, “...the sponsor of this video...” and here the emphasis seems to make her use “thee” : https://youtu.be/LNFw1XcRu_E